# How do I change google chrome language

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my Chrome language back to English?](https://superuser.com/questions/363408/how-do-i-change-my-chrome-language-back-to-english)

I'd like to change the language of the program (not the webpages or the spell-checking). I can't find any option in the parameters. When I installed the program, there was nowhere to select a language.

If I type "lang" in the search-box (in the chrome settings), I can only change the spell-checking.

Comment: Knowing your operating system would help. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: It's actually the same question as [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/363408/how-do-i-change-my-chrome-language-back-to-english). Voted to close as exact duplicate.