# Google Chrome is in German. How do I make it English?

Tags: google-chrome, localization

My Google Chrome is in German, and I don't speak German. How do I change it to English? I've tried looking at it to find similarities in language, but I can find the place to change language.

Answer (score 13):

A *slightly* faster way:

1. Type `chrome://settings/languages` in the address bar. (Yes, this works, just tried it in Chrome with German interface)

**NOTE: You will see the options in German, this is why I have provided pictures to guide you through.**

2. Click **Add**

[image]

2b. Choose English (can be UK, USA etc):

[image]

3. Highlight **English(chosen country)** and click on **Display Google Chrome in this language**.

[image]

4. Restart Chrome and the display language now should be English.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** look to the bottom right of your Google page and click this "Einstellungen" = Settings.

**Step 2** look to the left of the page and click this "Sucheinstellungen" = Language, or select the second word down from the top.

**Step 3** select the language your after, hope this helps took me a whole 10 mins to figure this out ha ha.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had this problem and it is very annoying.  I tried other browsers and had the same issue.  This led me to think that perhaps it was my computer so I typed language in my search box on Windows 10 and went to Region and Language in the settings menu and found that the Language was set to English, but the Country or Region was set to Germany.  I'm not sure how this happened, but changing to United States solved the problem.  Hurrah!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings from the menu on the upper right, search for language, select the language you prefer

Settings in german is Einstellungen

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and have since realised that ZenMate proxy was the problem causing Google to be in German.

Just thought I'd let you know just in case others have this extension also installed.

I had uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome but was still getting the problem until I disabled ZenMate.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I have figured it out and it fixed it for me without fiddle farting with any "settings" It's actually a simple fix...google geo locates you when you change countries.

Now think about it...when you travel you most often shut everything off and restart when you land wherever it is you're going...when you do that you have to sign in.....and all of sudden google is in Chinese or German or whatever language the language where you are geographically located at......but...if by chance you don't shut of you ipad or your iphone or tablet and you were logged in in say Germany....until you log out of all your devices Google still thinks your in Germany so you get German as the language.

Make sure you have logged out of google on all devices and all google accounts that connect with google...log back in and you should be golden...

In Gmail down in the bottom right hand corner there is an option to see activity click on that and it will show all recent activity in that module there is an option to log out of all devices click on that and that will clear it all up in one click for that single gmail account...IF you have multiple gmail accounts you must do the same for EACH account or you'll be back in Germany again...weird but I think it is really that simple...

Comment: Where does the OP mention he has been traveling?

Answer (score -2):

The most common problem for this is that you have a system on your PC to hide your IP address. Disable it,then it will go back to English.

Comment: Please include additional detail supporting this theory of yours as-is!!