# How not to get Swedish on an English web site, computer etc.?

Tags: google-chrome, language

When I opened Chrome and typed in *http://azure.microsoft.com*, I got immediately bumped to *http://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/*. The page is in Swedish and, while I do speak the language, two things annoy me.

1. What if that happens to a site in a language I don't master?
2. My girlfriend doesn't speak Swedish at all and she's angry. At me!

How can I stop that from happening? The computer is running English version of everything. The only connection to Sweden is the actual geographic location...

The same happens on another browsers too. I've clear up the whole cache, of course. I have all the settings in the browser set to English. What more can I do to keep my lady content?

Comment: Is this just happening in Chrome or other browsers as well?

Comment: @Jatin See the first sentence in the last paragraph. :)

Comment: Opps Sorry Missed it.

Comment: May be this http://superuser.com/questions/845144/google-chrome-is-in-german-how-do-i-make-it-english

Comment: @Jatin I don't think so; I saw that question too. I got the impression that in the question you linked Chrome itself was in German (the tool bar, all of the menus, etc) whereas this seems to be that Chrome is redirecting to the location specific version of particular sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website is likely directing you to their Swedish version because of your geographic location. It takes your IP address, finds out that the IP address is tied to Sweden, and then serves you a Swedish webpage.

You can possibly configure your browsers to spoof an English location: http://www.labnol.org/internet/geo-location/27878/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops into my head is using a proxy server in an English speaking country. Something like [Hola](https://hola.org/) for chrome (though I am not recommending that one specifically. Merely giving you an example of what I am talking about).

Another solution that might work is to disable the geolocation feature in Chrome. Though from [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/IkKxp-xkEqY) discussion, I'm not sure how well that works for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a VPN, preferably paid. (Go for the other solution, it's free)

The other solution is to replace that /sv-se/ with /en-us/ or /en-uk/