# To change Google chrome language

Tags: windows-10

Please help me to change the google chrome language from Arabic to English. i tried doing as per you tube instruction , but could not read Arabic language so could not change from half way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my Chrome language back to English?](https://superuser.com/questions/363408/how-do-i-change-my-chrome-language-back-to-english)

Comment: If that other question does not help, what have you already tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you show some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

To change the language of chrome you need to follow these steps :

- On your computer, open Chrome
- At the top right, click Settings
- At the bottom, click Advanced
- Under "Languages," click Language and choose the language you want
- Restart Chrome to apply the changes.

You can also access to :

```
chrome://chrome/settings/languages
```

Source : [Chrome Help Center](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)